# What is the difference between the beta version on FileHippo vs the official channel?

Tags: google-chrome

I usually download the latest version of Chrome from [FileHippo](http://www.filehippo.com/download_google_chrome/) since I am behind a proxy and the auto update functionality does not work well using the official channel. However, on my home PC I have installed Chrome beta from the [official site](http://www.google.com/landing/chrome/beta/) where the auto-update works as expected.

However, as of writing this, the latest beta according to FileHippo is 9.0.576.0 Beta while the latest update of beta on my home machine is 8.0.552.28 beta. In addition, FileHippo does not list my 'home version'.

So what's the difference between the two distribution channels and can someone shed some light on how get both my versions in sync to use the latest beta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the difference between two [channels](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/):

> **Beta channel** (currently 8.0.552.200): People who like to use and help refine the latest features
>   subscribe to the Beta channel. Every
>   month or so, we promote stable and
>   complete features from the Dev channel
>   to the Beta channel. The Beta channel
>   is more stable than Dev, but may lack
>   the polish one expects from a finished
>   product.
>
> **Dev channel** (currently 9.0.576.0): This developer preview channel is
>   where ideas get tested (and sometimes
>   fail). The Dev channel can be very
>   unstable at times, and new features
>   usually require some manual
>   configuration to be enabled. Still,
>   simply using Dev channel releases is
>   an easy (practically zero-effort) way
>   for anyone to help improve Google
>   Chrome.

Comment: I get that there is a Dev channel and beta channel. However, that would mean that the FileHippo releases are actually dev channel releases and not Beta as advertised?

Comment: It seems like FileHippo didn't get the difference between the two, or by mistake pointed to the wrong one.